# Why does binary subtraction work?

Tags: binary

I am unable to figure out why  $1010 - 1000 = 0010$ in binary is equivalent to $10-8=2$ in decimal? Why does subtraction work in binary just like in decimals?

Comment: Why do you think there's anything special about base 10? (In before all bases are base 10.)

Comment: Use the meaning of the notation : $a_n\cdots a_2 a_1 a_0$ means $a_0 + a_1\times 2 + a_2 \times 2^2 +\ldots$. Ask yourself how to subtract two such expressions and get an expression with only positive values of $a_k$

Comment: Perhaps you can think of it this way. Consider numbers
$$
A = a_0 p^0 + a_1 p^1  + a_2 p^2 + a_3 p^3 + \ldots
$$
$$
B = b_0 p^0 + b_1 p^1  + b_2 p^2 + b_3 p^3 + \ldots
$$
now what is $A-B$ ? Of course it's 
$$
A-B = (a_0 -b_0)p^0 + (a_1 - b_1)p^1  + \ldots
$$

Comment: Hey @MattiP. you beat me by 1sec